# vague php.log entry in OpenShift

Tags: openshift

I just started a new PHP 5.4 app with scaling, then tailed the logs and found an entry as follows being created in php.log every 2 seconds:

```
    - - - [21/Apr/2014:21:20:56 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 39627 "-" "-"
```

Does anyone know what's creating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is HAProxy sending the request as part of a scalable app.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. After knowing it was HAProxy, I did some research and found this similar post, with info on how to change the helth check interval: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/is-the-platform-polling-the-root-of-the-domain